# Reverse/swap post navigation in Wordpress default theme twentyseventeen

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I'd like to swap the next/previous navigation buttons on a single post page so when clicking the 'next post' button on the right it navigates to an older post. So reversing the chronological order.

This might be more straightforward by editing the theme directly but I can't seem to figure what code to add to the functions.php when doing this using a child theme?

Thanks heaps

Comment: Did you mean swap the `text` only or swap their position?

Comment: I mean to swap the chronological order, I think it would be to just swap their positions. So it's currently: On the left side "<- [Post Title] (which is an older post)" and on the right side "[Post Title] (which is a newer post) ->". I'd like it to be on the left side "<- [Post Title] (which is a newer post)" and on the ride side "[Post Title] (which is an older post) ->". Sorry if it wasnt clear before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the text only. It would be easy to edit [`single.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/single.php). But you want to swap their position, so this is the solution:

1. Put this function into `function.php`:
   https://gist.github.com/jaredchu/3e3bcb866240d1d32a3b4ae55905b135#file-the_reverse_post_navigation
2. In [`single.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/single.php), replace `the_post_navigation` by `the_reverse_post_navigation`:

https://gist.github.com/jaredchu/3e3bcb866240d1d32a3b4ae55905b135#file-single-php

Comment: Thank you, and that should work but it kindof breaks. The links are no longer besides eachother but now underneath eachother https://www.evernote.com/l/APt5-jVcGv1LW62qIOr_hxCxjp4O6IlAa38. Maybe it has something to do with the `rel=` attribute also being reversed? This should stay the same.

Comment: Are you using `the_reverse_post_navigation();`? Could you use the code in step 2?

Comment: I accidentally only replaced the name `the_post_navigation ` with `the_reverse_post_navigation ` of the function in `single.php` and not the code inside but if i do that it's no good either: https://www.evernote.com/l/APtUu2AA9F5Gbb_Z_Qu9iovEP-TO-L62pXA

Comment: @Ruben because my function containing `html` so the code is missing. I have posted it to gist. Could you check it again?

Comment: Much better but it is still missing part of the formatting: https://www.evernote.com/l/APtq9_D2rINIh7yVs-RVdTtliBjcF6WXhfo

Comment: The code in step 2 is missing too, copy it from the gist.